# How to correctly define variables in Python?

Tags: python, excel

Im writing a program so i can practise my spanish grammer. I come from the world of PLC programming and wanted to delve into Python to get 2 birds stoned at once. Below is the code, it however gives me an error on the syntax as its missing the var RandomVerbNumber in the on_change def. I have tried defining it outside of the def structures, but it will always make RandomVerbNumber have an incorrect value.

I have tried looking into classes and the **init** function. But that's not very clear to me yet.

```
import gspread
import random
import tkinter as tk

gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'credentials.json')
SpanishVerbs = gc.open('Spanish Verbs')

worksheet = SpanishVerbs.worksheet("EnglishSpanishList")

EnglishList = worksheet.col_values(1)
SpanishList = worksheet.col_values(2)
AmountOfRows = len(worksheet.col_values(1))
   
def on_next(event):
    RandomVerbNumber = random.randint(0,AmountOfRows)
    EnglishVerbLabel.config(text = EnglishList[RandomVerbNumber])
    print(EnglishList[RandomVerbNumber]," = ",SpanishList[RandomVerbNumber])

def on_change(event):
    if SpanishEntry.get() == SpanishList[RandomVerbNumber]:
        ResultLabel.config(text = "Correct")
    else:
        ResultLabel.config(text = "Incorrect")
    SpanishEntry.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
QuestionLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "Spanish Verb for:")
EnglishVerbLabel = tk.Label(root)
ResultLabel = tk.Label(root)
SpanishEntry = tk.Entry(root)
root.bind("<Return>", on_change)
buttonNext = tk.Button(root, text="Next", fg="black")
buttonNext.bind("<Button-1>", on_next)

QuestionLabel.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.E)
EnglishVerbLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
SpanishEntry.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
buttonNext.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
ResultLabel.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`RandomVerbNumber` is not defined in the function `on_change`. Why do you think it would be defined?

There does exist a variabel `RandomVerbNumber` in another function, but that's outside of the scope of `on_change`. Variables only exists within their scope.

Comment: I know its not defined outside of the on_next function. The problem i have is how do i correctly define it globally? Or should i be making it a class and define it there?

Comment: pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a randomised array defined in `main` as an argument into both methods, holding the index values of the words and `pop` the index value in the `on_next` method. Your edited code is below, my edits are marked with `NOTE` tags.

This method works because python lists are passed by reference.

```
import gspread
import random
import tkinter as tk

gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'credentials.json')
SpanishVerbs = gc.open('Spanish Verbs')

worksheet = SpanishVerbs.worksheet("EnglishSpanishList")

EnglishList = worksheet.col_values(1)
SpanishList = worksheet.col_values(2)
AmountOfRows = len(worksheet.col_values(1))
#NOTE:
randomisedList = random.sample(range(AmountOfRows), AmountOfRows)

#NOTE: event argument removed
def on_next(list):
    EnglishVerbLabel.config(text = EnglishList[RandomVerbNumber])
    print(EnglishList[RandomVerbNumber]," = ",SpanishList[RandomVerbNumber])
    list.pop()

#NOTE: event argument removed
def on_change(list):
    #NOTE:
    if SpanishEntry.get() == SpanishList[list[-1]]:
        ResultLabel.config(text = "Correct")
    else:
        ResultLabel.config(text = "Incorrect")
    SpanishEntry.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
QuestionLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "Spanish Verb for:")
EnglishVerbLabel = tk.Label(root)
ResultLabel = tk.Label(root)
SpanishEntry = tk.Entry(root)
#NOTE:
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event, list=randomisedList: on_change(list))
buttonNext = tk.Button(root, text="Next", fg="black")
#NOTE:
buttonNext.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, list=randomisedList: on_next(list))

QuestionLabel.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.E)
EnglishVerbLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
SpanishEntry.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
buttonNext.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
ResultLabel.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the modifications. I have tried running this but it keeps giving me the incorrect text, i think something is wrong with the value in the list. Im not sure how those lists work yet to begin with so im gonna look into that some more.

Comment: @wess I see, in my testing I just made sure the number was the same between both `on_change` and `on_next` methods. Also, `list` is a built-in python function, so changing the argument name might be a good idea.